# Error: StreamWriter exists in both System.IO version 4.0.10.0 and mscorlib version 4.0.0.0 DNX4.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mscorlib

I am using a StreamWriter in an MVC application on visual studio 2015.  It was working fine.  I then installed the .net version manager and beta 8 web developer tools.  Then I got the above error saying StremWriter exists in both System.IO and mscorlib.

I tried using the full names but that didn't resolve the error in Visual Studio.

Not quite sure how to resolve this aside from rolling back all the changes I made for beta8.

```
Global.json
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x86"
  }
}
```

project.json

```
"webroot": "wwwroot",
    "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-DecisionMaking-3b9017b0-7030-4235-9819-b3c8b1fb4a04",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta8",
        "System.IO": "4.0.10"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
            }
        }
    },

    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
    }
```

I can remove the System.IO from my project.json file but wanted to be sure this was the right move.  I assume mscorlib is included by default so my only option is remove System.IO.  I had to include this with beta 5 but maybe 8 no longer needs it.  Also wasn't sure about the older mscorlib version.

Comment: I strongly suspect you need to put `System.IO` in your `dnxcore50` dependencies, *not* in your project dependencies.

Comment: @JonSkeet that resolved it.  I can now build.  However I am getting a new error now where everything just closes.  Looks like I will be posting a question on that soon since it gives no indication why it just terminates.